# Solver Foundation multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, foundation, solver

I'm using the solver foundation Nelder-Mead-Solver to solve a nonlinear equation. The equation is accessed by a function/method (function evaluater), and for that reason I can't use the Context-Class and have to call directly the solver.

**The problem**:
When I want to run multiple solvers in parallel (multithreading), for example with the Task Class or the Thread-Class in C#, It seems to be that the solvers are get internally queued up and there is now difference in time between running a single solver or multiple solver.

**Question:**
Does anyone have the same issue?
And how I can run multiple solvers properly?

thank you very much!

Comment: I have a very similar problem; I'm using the standard solver, and can't figure out how to get it to work with multiple threads... I get an "exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe." error message when calling `SolverContext.GetContext()`

Comment: If you use the SolverContext-Class, then you can use the provided "Parallel-Solving capabilities".

Example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524505(v=vs.93).aspx

I think the error message with the "exePath..." doesn't belong to the solver foundation. It looks like a "Build Exe" Problem .